# Python sleep() inhibit print with comma?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I want to use the print with the comma (2.6), it works fine as long as you don't use time.sleep().

If you use the print with the comma, and then invoke sleep; the string will never print, if you are in a loop.

Example:

```
a=1
b=10
while a<b:
    print "yes",
    a=a+1
```

This works, you will see yes printed on the same line for 10 times.
But this won't work.

```
a=1
b=10
while a<b:
    print "yes",
    time.sleep(1)
    a=a+1
```

The expectation is that there will be a yes printed; then there is a second of wait, and then the next yes will be printed. Instead, you will see a string of 10 yes printed after 10 seconds.

Same goes if you use while loop; as long as the loop is running, and you have a sleep statement, the string won't print until the end.

To make it work, remove the comma.
This makes impossible to print a string on the same line, if you want to specify how long you want to wait between each string.

Is this a bug in the print function?

Comment: Looks like stdout isn't being flushed.

Comment: I reversed the direction of duplicate closure in hindsight, because the other version of the question seemed overall higher quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` does not automatically flush your output. You need to manually do it. This can be done by using `sys` module's `stdout.flush`

```
import sys,time
a=1
b=10
while a<b:
    print "yes",
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    a=a+1
```

Here is another way to prevent Python from using buffered stdio pipes  (Thanks to [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793296/python-sleep-inhibit-print-with-comma/30793307?noredirect=1#comment49636093_30793307))

Execute your program by using the `-u` option as in

```
python -u filename.py
```

From the man pages.

> `-u`
>   Force  `stdin`,  `stdout`  and  `stderr` to be ***totally unbuffered***.

One final way from Python3.3 is to use the `flush` argument to the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) function

> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the
>   `flush` keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.
>
> ***Changed in version 3.3***: Added the `flush` keyword argument.

Comment: this works....how come that you have to forcefully flush stdout? No newline means no flush?

Comment: Nope. It is implemented by the OS designers. The Linix terminal flushes only on newline. For files, it is flushed on file close.

Comment: I see, so this is a limitation of the terminal, not of the language.

Comment: The linux terminal has nothing to do with it at all. The linux _shell_ does, but just barely. The real issue is that stdio pipes are line-buffered by default when interactive, and Python 2 just relies on stdio. Python _could_ set the pipes to unbuffered, or you can even do it from within your own Python program, and neither bash nor your terminal will care.

Comment: @abarnert Oops. My bad choice of words. I meant shell when I mentioned terminal. It is mentioned here https://bugs.python.org/issue11633

Comment: @BhargavRao: But it's really not even up to the shell, it's up to Python (or, in Python 2, up to the platform's stdio implementation).

Comment: @abarnert Okay. So the problem is with the Cpython implementation which uses stdio pipes to print?

Comment: @BhargavRao: With Python 2, if you start the interpreter with the `-u` flag, it will open its stdio pipes in unbuffered mode (and binary mode). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @BhargavRao: Ultimately, yeah, I guess the fact that Python 3 stopped using stdio means you can say that stdio is the problem. In 3.x, Python uses a stack of adapters on top of raw file descriptors and does its own buffering. But what it does by default is pretty close to what stdio does on POSIX systems, so I think a better way to put this is that there _isn't_ a problem; stdout is line-buffered by default for good reasons. In 3.3, they added a `flush` keyword argument to `print` for when you want "mostly line-buffered, but not this particular `print` call".

Comment: @abarnert Thanks. I have added the two other mentioned ways to the answer. Do review it for any mistakes. Thanks again

Comment: @BhargavRao: It all looks good. I'm not sure you need to mention Python 3.x at all, because everything has changed so much, but it doesn't hurt for some future searcher who has what looks like the same problem because he doesn't know that 2.x and 3.x are different, so sure, why not.