# Why python don't print after a time.sleep()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm programming in python for almost 2 years and I found a really weird thing when watching some old code.

```py
import random, sys, time

try:
    while True:
        print(' ', str(random.randint(100,999)), end='')
        time.sleep(0.01)
except:
    sys.exit()
```

Following the syntax of this code my program should print a space and a random number from 100 to 999 forever, but this isn't happening.

When I run this code nothing appear on the screen until I press CTRL-C, even removing the try statement din't change anything.

I tried changing console (Windows terminal, powershell and CMD) but nothing happened.

Can please someone help me out with this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python keeps your print outputs in a buffer and waits for the end of the line before actually displaying it.
To force the display in Python 3, you can add the keyword `flush=True`.

```
import random, sys, time

try:
    while True:
        print(' ', str(random.randint(100,999)), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.01)
except:
    sys.exit()
```

Alternatively, you can:

- call `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print (Python 2-compatible);
- use the `-u` flag when executing the script (`python -u script.py`);
- set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5):

This answer [Python sleep() inhibit print with comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793296/python-sleep-inhibit-print-with-comma) suggests adding `sys.stdout.flush()` between the `print` and the `sleep`. Tested it - works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i gave the tick to another user to help him grow on this website

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random, sys, time
try:
    while True:
        print(' ', str(random.randint(100,999)), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of **PYTHON** are you using? I was able to run your code in my PC where I am using **PYTHON 3.7** in **PYCHARM 2019.2.4**.
It also ran successfully on **PYTHON 3.7.5 shell**

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10 and on Android 10 (beta)

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have a `while True` clause that's looping forever, Causing it loop recursively infinitely.

Here is the updated code

```py
import random, sys, time

try:
    while True:
        print(' ', str(random.randint(100,999)), end='')
        time.sleep(0.01)
        break
except:
    sys.exit()
```

I added a `break` statement to move to get out of the loop.

Comment: I don't think it's solving the problem OP has. Your code only prints the number once.

Comment: There is no recursion.

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid I had misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think you should remove this answer