# ray: python does not print after time.sleep

Tags: python-3.x, ray

I am using centos 8.2, python 3.6.8, ray 1.0.1 /3/, I have python souce code written in /1/, and result is shown in /2/, it only works for first print, but it does not work for second print and third print.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883447/why-python-dont-print-after-a-time-sleep) says I just put flush argument in print clause, but it does not work.

/1/

```
import ray
import time

ray.init();

@ray.remote
def f():
    a = 3;
    print("before print",flush=True);
    time.sleep(1);
    print("after print",flush=True);
    time.sleep(2);
    print("end",flush=True);
    return 1;

f.remote()
f.remote()
f.remote()
```

/2/

```
[sjj@localhost exer1Sleep]$ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
[sjj@localhost exer1Sleep]$ python3 raySleep.py
2021-03-10 14:26:15,322 INFO services.py:1092 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
(pid=42437) before print
(pid=42438) before print
(pid=42442) before print
```

/3/

```
[sjj@localhost exer1Sleep]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[sjj@localhost exer1Sleep]$ ray --version
ray, version 1.0.1.post1
[sjj@localhost exer1Sleep]$
```

[edited, add more] 
If I remove time.sleep, the print works ok. What does time.sleep make so that print disappears?

/4/

```
import ray
import time

ray.init();

@ray.remote
def f():
    a = 3;
    print("before print",flush=True);
    print("after print",flush=True);
    print("end",flush=True);
    return 1;

f.remote()
f.remote()
f.remote()
```

/5/

```
[sjj@localhost exer1Sleep]$ python3 raySleepWithout.py
2021-03-11 11:34:07,933 INFO services.py:1092 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
(pid=45246) before print
(pid=45246) after print
(pid=45246) end
(pid=45242) before print
(pid=45242) after print
(pid=45242) end
(pid=45245) before print
(pid=45245) after print
(pid=45245) end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also mentioned in ray discussion forum:

https://discuss.ray.io/t/ray-fails-to-log-or-print-messages-to-console-after-worker-previously-dies/805

It is an issue in current ray. Waiting for next release. Just mark the date March 11,2021. Ray 1.0.1 post