# Python - how to print to the console while typing input?

Tags: python, user-input, stdout, stdin

i'm writing a program where the user needs to be able to input into the console while other tasks are running in the background. the problem is that whenever the console prints a new line it appends it to the line where the user is typing and the inputs gets garbled.

here is the code that i wrote:

```
def screen_output():
    while True:
        print("something")
        time.sleep(1)

def user_input():
    while True:
        some_input = input("type in something: ")
        print(f"you typed: {some_input}")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=screen_output, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=user_input, daemon=True)

t1.start()
t2.start()

while True:
    pass
```

and this is the output that i get:

```
something
dfgdfgdfgdfgsomething
dfgdfgdfg
you typed: dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
type in something: something
dfgdfgherherhsomething
erherh
you typed: dfgdfgherherherherh
type in something: erherhsomething
reherherh
you typed: erherhreherherh
type in something: erhsomething
rherherherhersomething
hztzutzusomething
ztutzasdsomething
asdasdasd
you typed: erhrherherherherhztzutzuztutzasdasdasdasd
type in something: something
asdasdasdasdassomething
d
you typed: asdasdasdasdasd
type in something: asdasdsomething
something
```

ideally it would look something like this:

```
something
you typed: dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
something
you typed: dfgdfgherherherherh
something
you typed: erherhreherherh
something
something
something
something
you typed: erhrherherherherhztzutzuztutzasdasdasdasd
something
something
you typed: asdasdasdasdasd

type in something: asdasd
```

any ideas how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: make the thread that prints something also print what the user has typed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want garbled input/output, you will have to make it sequential.

A good way to use that is to use a `Lock`.
Threads should acquire that `Lock` before `print`-ing and before using `input` and release it afterwards.

Here is your code modified with a `Lock`:

```
import time
import threading

iolock = threading.Lock()


def screen_output():
    while True:
        iolock.acquire()
        print("something")
        iolock.release()
        time.sleep(1)


def user_input():
    while True:
        iolock.acquire()
        some_input = input("type in something: ")
        print(f"you typed: {some_input}")
        iolock.release()
        # Let this thread sleep as well, otherwise it
        # will crowd out the other thread.
        time.sleep(1)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=screen_output, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=user_input, daemon=True)

t1.start()
t2.start()

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: right, but the first function now only outputs 1 line and then it goes back to the input where it blocks. both threads need to be able to run independent of each other and the first one needs to print without running over the input box. also the input box needs to run at all times but the output function shouldn't write anything on top of the input box.

Comment: Did you try it with the added `time.sleep` to the second thread? And please update your question with the additional requirements. It sounds like you might want to try a library like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea on what you could do: separate the space for printing and for input in the console, you could use ANSI escape codes to move the cursor up a line and to the end of the line, print a newline \n and the message, kinda like the interface of a messenger app. I haven't tried this before, but it could work.
I'll edit this response after trying it.

Edit: I finally managed to do it, it required more than just printing \n, but these responses helped with it: [printing above the previous prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71087379/19338401), [printing after the time.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883447/why-python-dont-print-after-a-time-sleep#:%7E:text=Python%20keeps%20your%20print%20outputs%20in%20a%20buffer,%28100%2C999%29%29%2C%20end%3D%27%27%2C%20flush%3DTrue%29%20time.sleep%20%280.01%29%20except%3A%20sys.exit%20%28%29).

```py
import time
#If you are using windows you also have to do this:
#from os import system
#system("")

def screen_output():
  msg="something"
    while True:
      with threading.Lock():
        print("\x1b[s\x1b[1A\x1b[999D\x1b[1S\x1b[L"+msg+"\x1b[u", end="",flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)

def user_input():
  while True:
    some_input = input("type in something: ")
    print(f"you typed: {some_input}")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=screen_output, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=user_input, daemon=True)

t1.start()
t2.start()

try:
  while True:
    pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  sys.exit(1)
```

Edit 2: To leave a space in between the writing going on at the bottom and the messages moving up you can: first write a newline at the beggining of the program, replace \x1b[1A with \x1b[2A in screen_output to move two lines instead of one, and alter the function user_input:

```py
def user_input():
  while True:
    some_input = input("type in something: ")
    with threading.Lock():
      print("\x1b[s\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\x1b[1A",end="", flush=True)
      print(f"type in something: {some_input}")
      print(f"you typed: {some_input}",end="\x1b[u",flush=True)
      print("")
```

So when you finish entering the input, the input line get's erased and re-printed where the former division line was, then the "you typed: {some_input}" message gets printed, and finally it adds again the divison line.
I did this the way I did because couldn't figure out how to stop input() from adding the echo newline, so I just "copied" the input line and filled the division line with it.